# End quotation mark syntax

Tags: python-3.x

When i try running this code on 3.7.3 python it comes up with "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" pointing at the end quotation mark. What is wrong?

Ive just started to code and I'm running this on visual studio code on python 3.7.3

`Illinois= input(f"where did you grow up")`

Comment: Are you certain about the version?

Comment: You haven’t copied and pasted the code by any chance? So the quotation character is not a speech quotation mark “”" etc